# array is not displaying the value it contains in brackets

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[This is the {this.state.userCourse}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGljc.png)
[This is the problem I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1pmL.png)
I won't retrieve it's value of array.
Is that because of wrong method, or syntax problem?

```
this.state.userCourse.map((course) => {
      db.doc(course).get().then(
            snapshot => {
              //this.setState(prevState => ({registeredCourse: [...prevState.registeredCourse, snapshot.data().name]}))
                console.log(snapshot.data().name)
                arr.push(snapshot.data().name)
                }
              )
            })
```

Comment: const arr = []
    var db = firebase.firestore()
    this.state.userCourse.map((course) => {
      db.doc(course).get().then(
            snapshot => {
                console.log(snapshot.data().name)
                arr.push(snapshot.data().name)
                }
              )
            })
    {console.log(arr)}

Comment: What error you are getting

Comment: Be careful with the chrome dev tools, it can change how an object really is structured to display it correctly in its console window. Be sure of the data you get in snapshot by doing `console.log(JSON.stringify(snapshot.data().name));`.

Comment: @QuentinGrisel is definitely right about it. You should definitely find another way to check type of the data structure you are working with

Comment: I didn't get any error@AadilMehraj.

Comment: @QuentinGrisel, the snapshot is already in string, it's just because nothing shows in the bracket, and when I return the data with div, it doesn't appear. and I can't use index like arr[0] to get the data

Comment: Just try the json.stringify on snapshot.data() and give us the real shape of your object please, because if `name` is supposed to be an array with two keys, then there is no problem with the code you give us, at least for me ^^

Comment: @QuentinGrisel, I updated the photo for {this.state.userCourse}, that's exact;u what I want. I tried JSON.stringify() it didn't work either. I can't even map out the values of the {arr}

Comment: The purpose of JSON.stringify is for you to display it in the console to show us its shape (If possible of course). By the way, I noticed there is two double quote around the values on the screen https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1pmL.png maybe it has something to do with your problem. Also what do you have in `arr` after the push ?

Comment: I solved it with creating a state@QuentinGrisel

this.setState({
                                              registeredCourse: [...this.state.registeredCourse,snapshot.data().name]
                                            })}